# d3 event targets

Tags: d3.js

Is there a way to access the event target (the DOM element) without using `this`? I'm inside an object and I want `this` to be bound to the object itself. The global `d3.event` doesn't store the target apparently - `d3.event.target` doesn't work. Any clue?

Edit: here is the code I'm running (it's coffeescript):

```
@nodes = @svg.selectAll('g.node')
  .data(@nodes, (d) -> d.key)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'node')
  .attr('transform', (d) => "translate(#{@x d.x},#{@y d.y})")
@nodes.append('svg:rect')
  .attr('width', @x 100)
  .attr('height', @y 50)

node_drag = d3.behavior.drag().origin(Object).on('drag', @drag_move)
@nodes.call node_drag


drag_move: (d, i) ->
  console.log d3.event.target
```

The browser console output is

```
function e(){this.on("mousedown.drag",t).on("touchstart.drag",t)}
```

Same thing if I add a `debugger` statement and manually inspect the object. For some reason `d3.event.target` returns a function rather than the event object.

Comment: I've used `d3.event.target` successfully - can you post the example where it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recreate this, and I'm tempted to think it should be logged as a bug - I don't see any use in passing the drag control itself as `d3.event.target`.

Fixing seems to be easy in this case - just call the drag behavior on the `rect` selection instead:

```
@rect = @nodes.append('svg:rect')
  .attr('width', @x 100)
  .attr('height', @y 50)

node_drag = d3.behavior.drag().origin(Object).on('drag', @drag_move)
@rect.call node_drag
```

However, I could see this being quite annoying if you had multiple elements in your node group and wanted to understand which was being dragged.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this problem by reset the value of d3.event.target in the dragmove function:

d3.event.target =  event.target;

then the d3.event.target becomes the target DOM element instand of a function like drag()...